# Why does the fixed point algorithm only converge to one fixed point?

Tags: numerical-methods

For example, the function $f(x)=x^2$ has fixed points $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$, but the algorithm can only converge to $(0,0)$. Does anyone have a good explanation of why this is so?

Comment: Please be more clear about which algorithm you're talking about.

Comment: The idea is that to solve the equation f(x)=x, you estimate the solution for x as x_0 and let x_1=f(x_0), x_2=f(x_1), x_3=f(x_2), etc. This should converge to an approximate solution for x.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Because if you guess something between $0$ and $1$ and then square it, it will get *smaller*.  Thus the iterations will go toward $0$, not $1$.

Comment: It's relatively easy to show that $x=0$ is an attracting fixed point and that $x=1$ is repelling using cobweb diagrams or the first derivative test.  This is a typical homework exercise.

Comment: To add, it seems like you are talking about the fixed point theorem. Note that the theorem does not apply here as $f:x\mapsto x^2$ on $[0,1]$ does not satisfy the hypotheses of the fixed point theorem.

Comment: @AndrewZhang  what fp theorem are you talking about?

Comment: The contraction mapping theorem

Comment: Read about [attractors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attractor). Point (0,0) is an attractor, while (1,1) is an unstable equilibrium.

Comment: Also, [this link](https://www.complexity-explorables.org/flongs/logistic/) talks about attractors and repellers.

Answer (score 0):

It can be easily shown that if $z$ is a fixed point of $f$ and $|f'(z)|>1$, the fixed point method, $x_{n+1} = f(x_n)$ cannot converge to $z$, unless by chance we have that $x_k = k$ for some $k$ (and, even then, round-off errors can prevent convergence).

What is behind this fact is that, for differentiable $f$, there will be a neighbourhood of $z$ where $|f'|>1$ and so, for large enough $n$, we have that
$$
|x_{n+1} - z| = |g'(\xi)||x_n-z| > |x_n-z|, \quad \xi \in [x_n, z],
$$

so the error is increasing, implying that there is no convergence.

This is the case in your example, where we have that $f'(1)=2$.